# The onActivityResult method is not called

Tags: java, android

From the *first activity* I would like to go to the *second*, then from the *second* to the *third*. In the *third activity* I would like to enter the name in EditText, then after pressing the button, go to the *first activity* and at the same time send the information entered in the *third activity*.

I met with two situations, the *first situation*: the finish () method ends with calling super.finish (). Unfortunately, in this case, instead of returning to the first activity, I return to the second activity.

The *second situation*: the finish () method ends with the startActivity (i) call. Unfortunately, in this case the method in MainActivity - onActivityResult is not called, which will result in the lack of data entered in the third activity.

How would I normally receive data from my third activity?

This is my code:

First:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewInformation;
    Button button_GoToSecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewInformation = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button_GoToSecond = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button_GoToSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent i) {

        if((requestCode == 1) &&(resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

            String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
            textViewInformation.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button_GoToThird;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        button_GoToThird = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button_GoToThird.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Third (First version):

```
public class Third extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_Data;
    Button button_SendData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        editText_Data = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button_SendData = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button_SendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public void finish() {

        String name;
        name = editText_Data.getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(Third.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", name);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

And Third (Second version):

```
public class Third extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_Data;
    Button button_SendData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        editText_Data = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button_SendData = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button_SendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public void finish() {

        String name;
        name = editText_Data.getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(Third.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", name);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `finish` method to:

```
public void finish() {

    String name;
    name = editText_Data.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(Third.this, MainActivity.class);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("name", name);

    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK, bundle); 
}
```

Comment: Where should I receive data? Can it still be an onActivityResult method? Because I did everything according to your recommendations, but I still have the impression that this method is not called. Unless I am trying to receive this data in an inappropriate way. Could you give me a hint as to what should I do when I receive data? Because I tried in all ways and nothing ...